# mover una imagen sin eliminar el fondo en pygame

Tags: python, pygame

necesito un código que logre mover una imagen sin eliminar su fondo, quiero hacer que mi personaje se mueva, pero abajo de este ya hay algo de importancia, es por así decirlo, la carretera que el jugador hizo y después necesito que este pase por esta ultima (SOLO NECESITO QUE ALGUIEN LOGRE MOVER LA IMAGEN SIN CAMBIAR O BORRAR EL FONDO), también me serviría si en vez de ser una imagen fuese un pygame.draw.rect
gracias

```
run3 = True
```

def auto():
imagen = pygame.image.load("cuadrado_rojo_400x400.png")

```
x = 10
y = 10

reloj = pygame.time.Clock()
while True:
    for eventos in pygame.event.get():
        if eventos.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()
    pulsada = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if pulsada[K_w]:
        y -= 5
    if pulsada[K_s]:
        y += 5
    if pulsada[K_a]:
        x -= 5
    if pulsada[K_d]:
        x += 5
    reloj.tick(25)
    ventana.fill(0,0,0)
    ventana.blit(imagen,(x,y))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: NO ES NECESARIO QUE GRITES :) Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio (de paso obtienes tu primera [medalla](/help/badges)).

Comment: podrías haber puesto un código funcional.

Answer (score 0):

¿necesito? Hay que poner un código medianamente funcional, lo que pusiste no se le arrima ni cerca, pero como es muy simple lo voy a terminar. No hay nada que explicar, la función rect esta detallada con los parámetros que necesita para funcionar, por comodidad uso un alias.

```
import pygame as pg

pg.init()
ANCHO = 800  
ALTO =  600 
AZUL = (0,0,255)


ventana = pg.display.set_mode((ANCHO,ALTO))
reloj = pg.time.Clock()

fondo = pg.image.load("imagen1.png")
imagen = pg.image.load("imagen2.png")

def cuadro(superficie,x,y,ancho,alto):
    pg.draw.rect(superficie,AZUL,(x,y,ancho,alto))
```

están más que claros los parámetros: donde,color y tupla con  x, y, ancho y alto.

```
cuadro_ancho = 60
cuadro_alto = 60
cuadro_pos_x = 340
cuadro_pos_y = 500
cuadro_vel_x = 0
cuadro_vel_y =0

jugando = True

while jugando:
    reloj.tick(30)    
    for eventos in pg.event.get():
            if eventos.type == pg.QUIT:
                exit()    
    pulsada = pg.key.get_pressed()
    if pulsada[pg.QUIT]:    
        jugando = False 
        
    if pulsada[pg.K_w]:
        cuadro_vel_y = -10
    if pulsada[pg.K_s]:
        cuadro_vel_y =10
    if pulsada[pg.K_a]:
        cuadro_vel_x = -10 
    if pulsada[pg.K_d]:
        cuadro_vel_x =10
 
    cuadro_pos_x+= cuadro_vel_x
    cuadro_pos_y+= cuadro_vel_y 
    cuadro_vel_x= 0
    cuadro_vel_y =0
     
    ventana.blit(fondo,(0,0))
    ventana.blit(imagen,(cuadro_pos_x,cuadro_pos_y))
  
    pg.display.update()  
    
pg.quit()
```

Comment: Recuerda que no es necesario responder preguntas, si consideras que necesita detalles, deja un comentario y reporta la publicación, así otros se encargarán de revisarlo y tomar la acciones necesarias

Comment: @Christian no necesita detalles, me causa gracia que no pone unas 6 líneas que lo dejaría funcional.

Comment: eso es parte de proveer un ejemplo completo, mínimo y verificable. Esperemos a que OP responda y acepte tu respuesta :D

Comment: lamento no haber puesto un código funcional, no me di cuenta de que me faltaban un par  de cosas, una disculpa